# How do I use wxUpdateUIEvent for changing a panel interface?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

Here's the deal, I have a frame that contains a notebook, with only 1 page, The thing is I've been trying to created 2 class panels that use the same page depending on which EVT_BUTTON is clicked. (But that doesn't seem to work in no way I've tried because the panel doesn't redraw itself upon the EVT_Button)

Mini Example:

```
class HomePage(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent)
    wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent,size=((1000,500)))
    b1 = wx.Button(self,-1,'Fake Button') (binding blah blah) 


class MainApp(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,title='Test App',size=((1024,600)))
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title,size)        
    self.mainPanel = wx.Panel(self,-1)

    self.NotebookPane = wx.Notebook(self.mainPanel,-1,size=((1000,500))
    self.page1 = HomePage(self.NotebookPane)
    self.NotebookPane.AddPage(self.page1,'Home Page')
```

Now what I want to do is have it to where if a button is clicked it changes the interface of the HomePage panel. To my knowledge I know I'm suppose to use wx.UpdateUIEvent in some way but I don't really know how to set it up. How to bind it or anything else as the documentation leaves with with alot of questions. So lets just say I want the home page to add a second button and a textctrl button, but remove the button already in it on _*init*

How do I do that, I guess once I understand that I could learn how to do more but I need my foot in the door.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you basically want to swap in one panel in place of the other. If that's so, then you're in luck as I wrote a [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/16/wxpython-how-to-switch-between-panels/) on that a couple years ago. The concept is the same for swapping single-page Notebooks too, although I don't know why you'd want a single page notebook. You don't even need the UpdateUIEvent.

Comment: Well im kind of new to user interfaces and I thought it was the best way to do it.

Comment: That's alright. You gotta start some place. To be honest, I don't think I've ever used UpdateUIEvent in the nearly 6 years I've used wxPython though.